# Symfony 3 assets no update

Tags: caching, nginx, docker, symfony

I've init new projet in Symfony 3 with nginx and docker. It worked nice but my assets doesn't update in `web/assets/bundle.js`. Is i check my `bundle.js` after update, i see the old version.

I've remove the Symfony cache and my browser, but no result :

`php bin/console assets:install`

My nginx config :

```
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}
http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log off;
  error_log off;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
  open_file_cache max=100;
}
```

And Symfony :

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
    server_name 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 myApp.local;
    root /var/www/lfdw/web;
    location ~ ^(.*)/(app|app_dev|app_test|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_access.log;
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a local install the new assets wouldn't install at all.what i did was deleting the whole bundles directory in web and regenerated the assets.

Another hacky way would be to delete your vendors and `composer install`

If you are in prod you probably just need to execute this command:

`app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#e-dump-your-assetic-assets

Comment: I'm in dev environnement, not prod :) And yes, if i remove my bundle.js and recreat, the file is update :(

Comment: What do you mean by bundles.js? The path should be web/bundles/nameofyourbundle/js/jsfile.js if you placed it in Resources/public/js/jsfile.js

Comment: my bundle.js is a simple javascript file, placed only in web/assets, not in app/

Comment: Thats' why assets install has no effect it is for assets placed in Resources/public.If you place your file directly in web you don't need the command

Comment: Okay, i understand for assets:install. But my file in web/assets doesn't update. I've clear cache, but no result. If i restart my server (with docker-compose start/stop), my assets are update :/

Comment: Is the original file in web/assets?

Comment: Yes, my assets are only in web/assets

Comment: Nop, always old version. He change if i restart my server width docker-compose start.

Comment: since you put your file directly into web it should act like any other file in your project.I think you should look in the docker side of things for the problem.Sorry i can't help you more